# Rails 4, show attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

If i want to submit fields of nested resources instead of parent. How can I do this?

I've got two models: Product and Product_details.

```
=form_for @product do |f|
  =f.fields_for product_details do |ff|
    =ff.radio_button :price, ff.price
  =f.submit
```

So I need to submit the form above to product_details_controller instead of products_controller.

If I do form_form product_details I got something like "to_key" undefined..

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for) can help you.

**for example:-**

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks
  accept_nested_attributes_for :tasks, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

**in the view**

```
<% form_for @project do |project_form| %>
  <% project_form.fields_for :tasks do |task_form| %>
      <p>
        <div>
          <%= task_form.label :name, 'Task:' %>
          <%= task_form.text_field :name %>
        </div>
     </p>
   <%end%>
<%= project_form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**so @project.save will save the child tasks too.Also you can modify the controller code and do it the way you want**

**try it on rails console**

```
>> project = Project.first
=> #<Project id: 1, name: "Nested models patches", created_at: "2009-01-22 11:17:15", updated_at: "2009-01-22 11:17:15", author_id: 1>
>> project.tasks
=> [#<Task id: 1, project_id: 1, name: "Write 'em", due_at: nil, created_at: "2009-01-22 11:17:15", updated_at: "2009-01-22 11:17:15">,
#<Task id: 2, project_id: 1, name: "Test 'em", due_at: nil, created_at: "2009-01-22 11:17:15", updated_at: "2009-01-22 11:17:15">,
#<Task id: 3, project_id: 1, name: "Create demo app", due_at: nil, created_at: "2009-01-22 11:17:15", updated_at: "2009-01-22 11:17:15">,
#<Task id: 4, project_id: 1, name: "Scrutinize", due_at: nil, created_at: "2009-01-22 11:17:15", updated_at: "2009-01-22 11:17:15">]

>> project.tasks.second.name = "" 
=> "" 

>> project.valid?
=> false
```